# Ruby on Rails 4. All HTML inputs are selected on any page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have rails app and all my HTML inputs are selected as shown on the picture below. Can you help me to fix it? i really don't know why all my inputs are selected by default on every page

[image]

EDITED:

When i select manually one of this field:

[image]

```
application.css.scss:

 *
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

my CSS (took from tutorial, but if i remove all of this, then nothing changes):

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";


/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$gray-medium-light: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* miscellaneous */
.toolbar-button {
  color: darkblue;
}

label {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.orders_caption {
  float: left;
  alignment: left;
  color: black;
}

/* universal */

#error_explanation {
  color: red;
  ul {
    color: red;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  }
}

.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
  .form-control {
    color: $state-danger-text;
  }
}

header {
  div {
    ul {
      float: right;
      li {
        float: left;
      }

    }
  }
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $gray-light;
}

/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  &:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/* footer */

.system {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.order-attribute {
  float: left;
}

.order-value {
  float: right;
  width: 220px;
  .value-text {
    text-align: right;
  }
}

tr, th, td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  horiz-align: center;
}

.order-params {
  width: 90%;
}

.top-buffer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.top-buffer-small {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

hr {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
}

.load-planning {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Finally an HTML file:

```
application.html.erb:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all',
                          'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <% flash.each do |message_type, message|
     if message_type=='success' || message_type=='danger'%>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>

And my HTML:

<% provide(:title, "Order Release: "+@order_release.purchase_order_number) %>
<div class="container order-params">
  <%= form_for(@order_release) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/order_error_messages' %>
      <div class="row"><h3>Parameters</h3></div>
      <div class="row top-buffer-small">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <%= f.label 'Purchase Order Number' %>
          <div class="order-value"><%= f.text_field :purchase_order_number, class: 'form-control' %></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <%= f.label 'Delivery Status' %>
          <div class="order-value"><%= @order_release.status.humanize %></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row top-buffer-small">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <%= f.label 'Delivery Date' %>
          <div class="order-value"><%= f.date_select :delivery_date, class: 'form-control' %></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <%= f.label 'Handling Unit Quantity' %>
          <div class="order-value"> <%= f.text_field :handling_unit_quantity, class: 'form-control' %></div>
        </div>
      </div>
etc...
```

Comment: Seems like a CSS problem, can we see HTML and CSS for those inputs?

Comment: Are the fields really selected like if you click into a field or is it just a `CSS` pseudo selected?

Comment: i think it is pseudo, i have edited my question and added screen when i select one of these fields manually

Comment: First of all, please follow the instructions from [Bootstrap SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) to install Bootstrap properly. They say there that you shouldn't use `*= require` or the your other stylesheets will not be able to access the Bootstrap mixins or variables anymore. I made the same mistake. It's easy to read over it :).

Comment: Do you have any other CSS files in your project?

Comment: Yes, but the are empty

Comment: Thx! i've removed '*= require'  and it works!!!

Comment: Nice catch @Tobias :)! You should have the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the instructions from [Bootstrap SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) to install Bootstrap properly.

They say there that you shouldn't use `*= require` or your other stylesheets will not be able to access the Bootstrap mixins or variables anymore.

I made the same mistake. It's easy to read over it :).